# DELL XPS 9570 only boots with a disconnected AC/DC adapter

Tags: laptop, bios, dell-xps

I have a 2 years old DELL XPS 15 9570 which only boots (with a success rate ~25%) with a disconnected power adapter.

When the adapter is plugged in, it just doesn't turn on even through the keyboard lights are constantly on. When booting of the battery I just have to push the power button for a bit longer.

When it boots it typically stays on for 2-5 minutes and then it turns off without a warning. After the laptop is booted it works absolutely fine, no feature is compromised. It always takes at least half an hour (with or without charging) to boot it again. The CMOS battery has been recently replaced.

Plugging the adapter after it boots sometimes helps to run it for longer, but I haven't tried it much.

Just before calling it a `motherboard failure` I'd like to give it an extra chance and try and understand the actual cause of the problem. It'd be really pity to lose it over some unexplainable issue like this.

The problem started recently after an unsuccessful BIOS update which in turn was brought in by Windows update.

Sorry for a sporadic explanation any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a 2 years old DELL XPS 15 9570 which only boots (with a success
> rate ~25%) with a disconnected power adapter.

Use the Dell Driver Updater to update all drivers but especially BIOS (UEFI) and Power.

Restart after this even after interim restarts.

Update Windows completely.

Test the AC Adapter Operation.

If after the above, the AC Adapter does not function correctly (will not start plugged in),  then now is the time to get the machine serviced.